# Storing variables in CPU registers

Tags: c, cpu-registers

I have read that CPU registers are limited and the value can also get stored in auto.

How to confirm if the variable is stored in a register in C?

What kind of variables can be stored?

Comment: `register` can be ignored by the compiler and will be by many modern compilers for allocating registers. Today only the side-effect of not being allowed to take its address is the only relevant use-case. For the rest: your question is too broad. Read how CPUs work, the reference manual of your **specific** CPU and the ABI of your platform.

Answer (score 4):

Most compilers support a flag such as `-S` or `/S` that generates assembly-language output.  You can inspect this code to see whether your compiler stores a given variable in a register at a given point.

There is no type guaranteed to fit into a register.  In fact, some stack-based machines, including the hardware implementation of JVM in Andrew Tannenbaum’s textbook, do not have explicit registers at all.  However, an `int` usually is the same size as a register (64-bit environments that define `int` and `long` as 32-bit for backward compatibility are exceptions), a pointer usually holds a machine address and therefore is usually the same size as a register (segmented memory models such as 16-bit x86, where addresses fit into two registers, are exceptions), and `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` hold array indices and are therefore usually the same size as a register (The x32 target, which has 64-bit code but a 32-bit memory space, is an exception).  Most CPUs have floating-point registers that can each hold a `double` to do math on it, but some don’t.

If what you want is fast portable code, your best bet is to use the types such as `int_fast16_t` and `uint_fast32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.  These are guaranteed to be the usually-fastest size that’s at least wide enough. and on normal targets, that’s going to be the size of a machine register.