# Variable creation on the stack in C

Tags: c, function, stack

I am wondering if a variable is created on the stack or not. Consider the following three functions f,g and h with the variable b:

```
void f(int a) {
    int b;
    if (a == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // do sth with b;
    return;
}

void g(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return;
    }
    int b;
    // do sth with b;
    return;
}

void h(int a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        int b;
        // do sth with b;
        return;
    }
}
```

1. In which cases will b be created on the stack?
2. How does the compiler optimization level affect this behavior?
3. Is there one option which is preferable?

Comment: Putting variables on the stack is actually an implementation detail, the C specification doesn't say anything about it. However in reality all common compilers does that. And then *all* local (a.k.a. automatic) variables are placed on the stack, no matter where inside a function it is defined. Your second question is unanswerable since it depends on the compiler and can differ a *lot*. And for your third question, what option? Preferable to what?

Comment: Unless the variable is completely optimized out, it will be created on the stack. Whether it will be optimized out, is dependent on the other code of the function. If variable `b` is not used the compiler will optimize it in most of the settings

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP means "which of the three functions is preferable?"

Comment: If it's as @WeatherVane says, that you wonder which function is "best", then you forget one alternative: `void i(int a) { if (a != 0) { int b; /* do sth with b */ } }` And which is "best" is quite subjective.

Comment: ...which only has one `return` in the function which is always preferable for readable code.

Comment: @oliver-fhg: if a function don't change global state and returns `void`, any optimizing compiler will just [optimize it away completely](https://godbolt.org/z/j4Hpyd). Which is not even a big deal, since compilers today can analyze your loops and even [evaluate them at compile time](https://godbolt.org/z/KTtHxA).

Comment: @WeatherVane: well, that's debatable, I'd take guard clauses over a nested `if` which mutates a `result` variable any day of the week. :-P

Comment: @Groo yes I should have said "usually".

Answer (score 5):

> In which cases will b be created on the stack?

Usually all three, since `b` is an automatic variable. In some cases, the compiler may [store `b` in a CPU register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390495/storing-variables-in-cpu-registers), but you cannot force it to happen, it's the compiler's choice.

> How does the compiler optimization level affect this behavior?

Compiler dependent.

Since you assume that you do something (useful) with `b`, it will be probably not optimized out. If it does, which depends on the compiler and what is the actual work that you do with `b`, then `b` won't be created at all in the stack.

> Is there one option which is preferable?

Create variable `b` as close as possible to its usage, at the top of the block where it is needed.

I would go for `g()`, since it's the most laconic function (it uses the minimum amount of characters in contrast with the others, to achieve the same purpose). Moreover, it creates `b` just before its usage.

PS: Of course `g()` could use only one `return`, but you get the idea.

Comment: It might still be optimized out even if something useful is done

Comment: This is what I was thinking @M.M. Do you think that my edit improves the answer?

Comment: Local variables could also be held in CPU registers.

Comment: @Jabberwocky won't they need to be [marked as `register`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45614744/how-many-registers-are-used-when-a-variable-is-declared-using-register-storage-c) for that to happen?

Comment: "_Create variable b as close as possible to its usage._" This is a personal issue. I prefer to have them "as close as possible" but at the top of the block where it is needed. That allows to more easily spot where the variabe is declared.

Comment: @gsamaras no, the compiler is free to to generate the code he wants. BTW marking a variable with `register` will not guarantee that the variable will actually be in a register.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this is what I meant, but since the examples were limited, I paraphrased it, thanks, edited. Jabberwocky, you are correct, answer updated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> In which cases will b be created on the stack?
>   How does the compiler optimization level affect this behavior?

Impossible to tell without a specific system in mind. It depends on the calling convention and how the compiler optimizes the code. It may be allocated on the stack or inside a register.

That being said, your 3 cases are mostly about coding style. If `b` is needed and is allocated on the stack, that memory will probably get allocated early on no matter where the variable is placed. Or similarly, if the compiler is able to optimize memory use based on if the variable is used or not, the compiler will then allocate the memory just before the variable is used, regardless of where the variable declaration is located in the C source code.

> Is there one option which is preferable?

Generally, keep the variable declaration close to where it is used. If you can narrow the scope, it's always a good thing. But that's for the sake of reducing scope, avoiding namespace collisions, private encapsulation etc. Not for the sake of performance.

Answer (score -2):

Every function has your own frame(place where will be storing all local variables, parameters, etc.). All local variables is an automatic variables because they will be destroy after `return` operator. All variables which was created without (`malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, etc) will be stored on the stack. So, yes all variables in your code will be stored on the stack.

Comment: Not necessary. It may be put directly to CPU registers. You have no influence on that, it is compiler decision. Please note that variable cannot be created by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. These function only allocate memory, not creating variables. You still need memory location somewhere (stack?, not stack?) to store location of allocated memory.